# Visual code multiple line selection

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I select some word and vscode see the same word in the code it highlights it. But is there any way to select all the lines that are highlighted?
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc the code you want multiselect and press

On MacOS: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

On Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> like gerdi answered

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

Will select the next of the same in the code

Answer (score 0):

To select **all** the lines that are highlighted:

```
Ctrl+Shift+L  (and cmd+shift+L for mac)
```

from [vscode shortcuts reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference)